# How to generate randomness using a biased coin?

Tags: sampling, sample, random-generation, randomness

Imagine we have three people and we want to select one of them at random.

If we had a fair coin we could have tossed the coin twice to get one of the 4 outcomes and could have related the occurrence of any three of them with the first, second and third person..

How can we do this if we have a biased coin instead?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you're actually asking, and, as I suspect this is homework or self-study, you should add the self-study tag.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50295/given-a-coin-with-unknown-bias-generate-variates-from-a-fair-coin-efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this, is by what is known as the [von-Neumann trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin).

Imagine you have a biased coin where you get heads($H$) with probability $p$ and tails($T$) with probability $1-p$. Notice that if you throw the coin twice, the outcomes $HT$ and $TH$ are equiprobable with probability $p(1-p)$. You can simulate a fair coin by assigning the outcome $HT$ to $H$ and the outcome $TH$ to $T$. If you get one of the other two cases($HH$ or $TT$) you ignore them and repeat the experiment.

Now that you know how to simulate a fair coin, you can easily extend this to simulate throwing a fair coin multiple times by repeating the above experiment.

Note that this method can be very inefficient, especially when $p$ approaches $1$ e.g $p=0.99$. Since you are waiting for the first event $HT$ or $TH$, you are wasting a lot of throws since those two events only occur with probability $p(1-p)=0.0099$ each.

Comment: Mathematically correct...but practicality is unclear.  ¿What if $p=99.99999\%$? That seems like a long time to wait for a TH or HT

Comment: Yes indeed I should add that the method is inefficient.

Comment: I hope the moderators would agree a smiley emoji would be appropriate here.

Comment: :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: @Andreas G. wrote "Yes indeed I should add that the method is inefficient." On the contrary. The OP's method for getting someone else to do her/his homework or take-home test problem was very efficient.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone If it's homework, they are only hurting themself. Nevertheless, it's not clear(at least to me) that this is a homework exercise.

Comment: Its not a homework question.I am preparing for my exams, trying to solve question papers and got stuck at this sum.So wanted help.Thanks.