# How to generate a Bernoulli distribution based on a given Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: self-study, bernoulli-distribution, generator

We have a Bernoulli distribution which outputs 1 with probability C and outputs 0 with probability 1-C. C is unknown.

Now we would like to generate a new Bernoulli distribution that outputs 1 with probability X. Without using random numbers, how can we do that using the previous Bernoulli distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is not completely clear. I assume you mean Bernoulli process, rather than distribution?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Comment: Yes You can assume it is a Bernoulli process.

Comment: This seems related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50295/77222

Comment: also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354678/brain-teaser-how-to-generate-7-integers-with-equal-probability-using-a-biased-c