Unbiased estimator of mean divided by square root of second moment
Let $X$ be some random variable. Assume that
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}X,\,\delta = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2}$$
are well defined and finite (in other words $X$ has first two moments). Now suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d. with the same distribution as $X$.
Question.
I am interested in unbiased estimator of ratio
$$\frac{\mu}{\delta}$$
Are there nontrivial examples of such estimators in terms of sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$?
I will happily upvote partial answers – ones concerning typical distributions or answers relying on some extra assumptions.

I don't know if that exists. It's hard to find an unbiased estimator for a ratio where both the numerator and denominator are random variables. Happy if someone else has an answer though.

Careful! Many readers will automatically assume "$\sigma$" is the standard deviation of $X,$ but it's not. // This question strikes me as too broad, because the answer depends on what you assume about the distribution of $X.$  Could you narrow the question to a specific circumstance of concern to you?

@whuber I am not very accustomed with standard notation used in statistics, but you are certainly right I will replace $\sigma$ with some other name.
Indeed, the question is broad. It is on purpose, since I am curious (as non expert) if there exists general answer known to experts. Having said that I will edit question to allow also partial answers.

I suspect you have to at least restrict the distributions to those where the first two moments exist (sorry, Cauchy distribution). $//$ Is your $\delta$ supposed to be the square root of the variance, or do you really mean what you wrote?

@Dave first two moments exist $\Leftrightarrow$ mean and standard deviation exist. Or I am missing something?

I missed that you already gave that restriction. However, my question about what you mean by $\delta$ still stands. Should $\delta$ be the usual standard deviation (square root of the second central moment)? Right now, that is not what $\delta$ is.

We offer many posts on this topic.  Here is a focused search.  The hit at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502277 looks particularly appropriate to begin with.

@Dave I am interested in precisely in $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}X^2}$

@whuber Thank you. I will read thread you linked carefully.

@Slup It might be worth changing the question title to clarify that you are not asking about standard deviation.

@Dave thank you. It seems that I fall in exactly the same trap that you were warning against.

I'm taking it you intend this unbiased estimator to work for ALL probability distributions for which the expected value of the square is finite?

If $X$ has support on the positive half line with finite second raw moment, I could see this potentially making some kind of sense (and in that case a number of useful things might potentially be said). If it's intended to be more general, is there some context for this problem? I get the feeling we might potentially be wandering around the edge of an XY-problem pit trap.

@MichaelHardy Yes. There are such "universal" unbiased estimators for mean and standard deviation, if I am not mistaken.

@Glen_b Why question does not make sense for X supported on $\mathbb{R}$? Estimator of ratio $\mu/\delta$ (for vector valued variables) plays central role in Adam optimizer, which is widely used in machine learning. I was curious if there exists nontrivial unbiased estimator of this ratio for real valued random variable.

I know of a universal unbiased estimator for variance (assuming variance exists), but I do not know of one for standard deviation.

@Dave I meant variance. I apologize for the confusion.

If you had said $\mu/\delta^2$ rather than $\mu/\delta,$ it could be done, although maybe somewhat inefficiently: Use the fraction whose numerator is $X_1$ and whose denonimator is an unbiased estimator of $\delta^2$ based on $X_2,\ldots,X_n.$ I won't be surprised if that can be improved upon.
